# Definition of a RLE in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, run-length-encoding, rle

I'm looking to write a run length encoder in vb which when called, encodes the text of a input and sets it as the text of a label. I have the call coded, but the encoding definition is beyond any. Any ideas on how to write this encoder?

Comment: Probably a little off topic here.  Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or check nugets

Comment: Googling the topic gives several sample codes even in VB.Net.